# How to pass by value when dealing with rails associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a newbie, working with Rails. I'm trying to reassign an invitation object from one user to another user. Here's the controller

```
def create
@invitation = Invitation.new(invitation_params)
@trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
@invitation.trip = @trip
@invitation.attributes = {user: @trip.user, status: "Pending"}
authorize @invitation
if @invitation.save
  InvitationMailer.with(email: params[:invitation][:email], invitation: @invitation, trip: @trip).invite_email.deliver
  redirect_to trip_path(@invitation.trip)
else
  render :new
end

def accept
@invitation.attributes = {user: current_user, status: "Accepted"}
if @invitation.save
  redirect_to trip_path(@invitation.trip)
end
```

Problem is, when dealing with objects, passing by reference seems to be the only option. I can't reassign the @invitation.user without also overwriting @trip.user with current_user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like they’re sharing a variable, probably current_user that’s being changed. I can’t see how that’s happening in your code, but it might be elsewhere. You could try changing user_id instead.

Comment: @AJFaraday invitation.user_id = current_user.id does the same thing. It makes current_user take over trip.user as well as invitation.user.

Comment: You might need to share your model code. I can’t see a reason for this happening here.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is, when dealing with objects, passing by reference seems to be the only option.

Ruby is always pass-by-value, with no exceptions. It does not support pass-by-reference at all. The only mainstream languages I can think of right now that *do* support pass-by-reference are C++ (with the `&` sigil / operator), C# (with the `ref` keyword), PHP (`&`), and Perl. In C++, C#, and PHP, the default is pass-by-value, and you have to *explicitly* ask for pass-by-reference. Perl is the only one where pass-by-reference is the default, and in fact not just the default but the only option.

So, to repeat: Ruby is always pass-by-value. It is *impossible* to achieve pass-by-reference in Ruby. The semantics of the language just do not allow it. You would have to modify the language itself and change the interpreter/compiler (or write a new one), in which case it is no longer Ruby.

It is not quite clear from your code what, precisely, is going on, but one thing is 100% sure: pass-by-reference *cannot possibly be* the problem. You can stop investigating that avenue.

Comment: You are right. The problem was elsewhere.